# React set dimensions on window resize using debounce method

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, addeventlistener, debouncing

I am trying to set the window dimensions during window resize event using a debounce method. It seems that the dimensions are set only the first time that the code runs. When i am trying to resize the window the dimensions does not change. I create a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ciq1l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `timer` inside `return` part of `debounce`.

Another thing, any time you get inside `debounce` function you are assigned new `var timer`, so the check of `if (timer)` right after never gonna apply

```
// inside contructor
this.timerRef = React.createRef(null) // for react version > 16.3

debounce(func) {
      if (this.timerRef.current) clearTimeout(this.timerRef.current);
      this.timerRef.current = setTimeout(func, 100);
  }
```

**Edit**

Because you want to pass param to the event listener function (and need to use `()` activation), you suppose to take the whole function as a callback

```
 window.addEventListener(
      "resize", () =>  //adding () =>
      this.debounce(() => {
        this.updateDimensions();
      })
    );
```

or inside `debounce` you can refer directly to `this.updateDimensions`, and there is no need to pass `func` anymore and you can do like

```
window.addEventListener("resize", this.debounce)
```

without activate `debounce()`